# Модель игрока-человека в игре | WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется модель некоторой "настольной" игры (привожу упрощенно), например, крестики-нолики, в ней определен интерфейс игрока:

```
interface IPlayer
{
    Position GetMove(GameField field);
}
```

вспомогательные классы (`Position`, `GameField`, `GameState` и т. д.) и, собственно, сам класс игры:

```
class Game
{
    public GameField Field { get; private set; }
    public GameState State { get; private set; }
    IPlayer first, second;
    public IPlayer CurrentPlayer { get; private set; }

    public Game(IPlayer first, IPlayer second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Field = new Field();
        State = GameState.Proceed;
        CurrentPlayer = first;
    }

    public void NextMove()
    {
        ... // Проверка состояния игры и выброс исключения если ходы уже невозможны
        var position = CurrentPlayer.GetMove(Field.Copy());
        ... // Проверка корректности хода и его применение или выброс исключения
        ... // Проверка окончания игры и смена статуса
        ... // Смена текущего игрока
    }
}
```

Игровой цикл, например, в консольном приложении мог бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
ComputerPlayer first = new ComputerPlayer();
HumanPlayer second = new HumanPlayer();
Game game = new Game();
ShowField(game.Field);
while (game.State != GameState.Completed)
{
    game.NextMove();
    ShowField(game.Field);
}
```

С игроком-компьютером всё просто - реализуем в его коде алгоритм поиска лучшего хода. Он не зависит от представления.

Как быть с игроком-человеком? Он ведь по сути жестко связан с представлением. В консольном приложении я мог бы реализовать его примерно так:

```
class HumanPlayer : IPlayer
{
    public Position GetMove(GameField field)
        => ConvertToPosition(Console.ReadLine());

    Position ConvertToPosition(string s)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Получается, я должен реализовать игрока в части представления VM+V? Или нужно разделить его как-то на модельную и представленческую части?
Как организовать игровой цикл? Как предусмотреть возможность игры Человек vs. Человек?

Comment: не проще определять кому принадлежит следующий код и сделать отдельные классы, функции?

Comment: @codename0082016, о чем вы? Можно поточнее? CurrentPlayer - публичное свойство, поправил в вопросе, я могу узнать чей текущий ход в любой момент.

Answer (score 1):

Набросал пока такое решение:

```
class HumanPlayer : IPlayer
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Position> taskSource;

    public Position GetMove(GameField gameField)
    {
        taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Position>();
        Position result = taskSource.Task.Result;
        taskSource = null;
        return result;
    }

    public void SendPosition(Position position)
        => taskSource?.SetResult(position);
}
```

При вызове метода `GetMove` из `Game` поток, в котором бежит модель блокируется до того момента, пока кто-то (а это будет `VM`) не подтолкнет его вызовом метода `SendPosition`.

Надеюсь, кто-нибудь прокомментирует мой вариант и укажет на его недостатки или может кого-то мой ответ натолкнет на мысли и он напишет свой ответ. Буду рад любым комментариям и замечаниям.